# Logical or in policy condition AWS

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-iam, scp

I want to have a logical or between AWS policy which I then need to attach to SCP.
The motivation is to add a policy which applies in case one of 2 conditions are met.

```
{
        "sid": "OnlyT1T2Micro",
        "Effect": "Deny",
        "Action": ["ec2:RunInstances"],
        "Resource": ["arn:aws:ec2:us-east-1:accountid:instance/*"],
        "Condition": {
            "StringEquals": {
                "ec2:InstanceType": ["t1.micro","t2.micro"]
            },
            "StringEquals": {
                "ec2:Region": "us-east-1"
            }
        }
    }
```

In this case, I would like to deny Ec2 run instance API in case type is one of t1 or t2 micro or the region is us-east-1.
But in this snippet, it's a logical "and" between conditions which mean the policy would apply in case it's a (t1.micro or t2.micro) and (us-east-1 region), which I'm looking to add "or"

In order to save the text in the SCP (due to limit), I was looking for shrinking together in 1 policy 2 conditions with "or", in case there is an option

Hope this example is clear

Answer (score 6, accepted):

An SCP can contain multiple policies, at the moment your single policy will require all conditions to be met (as well as the resource pattern) before it will deny.

You should create a separate statement for each of these conditions whilst also removing the resource pattern if you're trying to deny access for those instance classes in other AWS regions.

Perhaps something like the below is more appropriate.

```
{
    "sid": "OnlyT1T2Micro",
    "Effect": "Deny",
    "Action": ["ec2:RunInstances"],
    "Resource": ["*"],
    "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
            "ec2:InstanceType": ["t1.micro","t2.micro"]
        }
    }
},
{
    "sid": "NotInUsEast1",
    "Effect": "Deny",
    "Action": ["ec2:RunInstances"],
    "Resource": ["*"],
    "Condition": {
        "StringEquals": {
            "ec2:Region": "us-east-1"
        }
    }
}
```

With this it will evaluate as if either the instance type is a `t1.micro` or `t2.micro`, or if the region is `us-east-1` then deny the action.

The only `OR` condition is between each statement, if you're trying to reduce the size of your statements try to group up similar statements. For example disabling common actions in the same statement, or if you you want to deny a number of regions add them all to the same statement rather than one statement each.

Comment: I reach the scp text limit. therefore was wondering if there is something thiner

Comment: You can have these both within the same policy? Or have you exceed the policy length?

Comment: I have to consider the policy length. There is SCP policy length limitation, which I haven't exceeded yet, but been there once, and I know we could get there. trying to avoid in advance in case there is an option

Comment: Unfortunately the only ORs are between statement. My advice would to try and compound similar conditions i.e. if you're trying to disable certain services all in us-east-1 you would include them in the same statement

Comment: If you change your answer and add this comment I'll approve that as an acceptable answer. Or maybe we could add on the negative option?

Comment: I have updated answer, you can always use the negatives such as `StringNotEquals` it overall depends on whether you want to whitelist or blacklist (generally go for the shorter approach).